# A full cryptic crossword

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

Eight clues are thematic and are clued by word-play only.  Each of these eight clues' word-play has an extra letter which is not part of the answer.  These letters cryptically indicate something, which when put together with the theme, one might expect to drink when enjoying the theme.  This (three words, (7,9,3)) must be stated to complete the puzzle.  All other clues are normal.

[image]

**Across**

8. Made an effort to follow beef rump (5)
9. Interrogate leaders of Turkey's 'egg' deliverers (7)
10. Fifty-one and a third of cereal parasites (4)
11. Chewed acorns and crushed dacite (10)
12. Reseated as a guest with starter of soup (8)
15. Baker's friends give direction in heartless agreement (6)
16. Electronic consent for Peeps (4)
18. Kiln for drying hops decorated with trout skin (5)
19. Stop crown of celery going off and relax (4)
21. Second ovary boiled with herb (6)
23. Moët 18 (sparkling!) (8)
25. Oven-cooked batter with hint of nigella and last of bangers (5,5)
28. Municipal egg-boxes turn whitish (4)
29. Swore and turned aside to trade rabbit's foot for its head (7)
30. Flutter an eyelid at wedge of cheese and bone marrow (5)

**Down**

1. Loud in icy café? Upheaval is able to produce the intended result (8)
2. Is bell rung for defamatory statements? (6)
3. More than half of soy beans are used for cheese (4)
4. For example entrails are not for everyone (4)
5. Note-density is variable -- plug music players in vertical stack (4-6)
6. The act of removing obvious half of lovage (8)
7. Coming in the year of our lord -- pie opening... (6)
13. ...try eggs (but scrambled) at famous address? (10)
14. Sparing cutting, withdrawing cheesewire finally (5)
17. Maybe beach workers abolish or emend holding (8)
20. Quiet and Latin -- country of islands (8)
22. Scoundrel and woman returning for manifestation of Shiva (6)
24. Themes of Optics discussed (6)
26. Verdi's work to help introduction of asparagus (4)
27. Weeps noisily: first of all save our breakfast sandwiches (4)

Comment: 13D is a very nice clue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The filled grid:

> [image]

Clue explanations (and some comments on things I didn't quite understand / found interesting):

> [image]

As for the theme...

> The eight modified entries are FRIED, GRILLED, SAUSAGES, TOAST, TOMATOES, BAKED BEANS, BACON, and EGGS. The wordplay for each of those entries includes an extra letter T. So, the thing being clued here is **ENGLISH BREAKFAST TEA**!

Comment: Thank-you for the feedback!  I chose *discussed* as the anagram indicator in 24D as it made for a good surface, I thought, and it has meanings of *debate* and *argue* which I would also use as anagram indicators.  Maybe I was wrong though.  The Schrödinger at 4D is definitely accidental though.

Comment: I think I see what you mean about 1D though now I've thought about it -- the definition I've given might clue (rot13: rssvpnpvbhf) better?  I did struggle a lot to find a way of clueing it that didn't include the word (rot13: rssrpg) and I think I've probably failed now.  But again, thank-you for the feedback, I shall try and improve.

Comment: @Narushiteli Yeah, I'm not quite sure I'd use either "debate" or "argue" as an anagram indicator - neither of those suggests that parts of an object are in the wrong place (in the way that, say, "messy", or "broken" does). And that's what I was thinking about 1D - off the top of my head, I'd probably go with something along the lines of "ability to make an impact" (or just "impactfulness")?

Comment: thank-you again, I shall take that on board!  I like impactfulness, and I think 1D wouldn't need much modification to use it as it stands either.